# Quantum Mechanics Lx operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

> Show that if the state $ \rvert\gamma\rangle $ is real, then the expectation value of each component of the angular momentum is zero. Does this imply the angular momentum is zero?

My Work:

$$ \langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x\rvert\gamma\rangle =\langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x\rvert\gamma\rangle^* =\langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x^*\rvert\gamma\rangle$$
$$l_x=\frac12(l_+ + l_-)$$
$$l_-^+= l_x  + _-^+il_y$$

Comment: $$ \langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x\rvert\gamma\rangle =\langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x\rvert\gamma\rangle^* =\langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x^*\rvert\gamma\rangle$$
$$l_x=yp_z-zp_y = -i \hbar(y\tfrac{d}{dz} -z\tfrac{d}{dy})$$
$$(l_x)^*=i \hbar(y\tfrac{d}{dz} -z\tfrac{d}{dy}) = -l_x$$
$$ \langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x\rvert\gamma\rangle=-\langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x\rvert\gamma\rangle$$
$$ 2\langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x\rvert\gamma\rangle=0$$
$$\langle\ \gamma\rvert l_x\rvert\gamma\rangle=0$$

Comment: $l_x$ is hermitian, so what you wrote $l_x^\dagger = -l_x$ is not true. Remember that the position representation of those operators is meant to be sandwiched between wave-functions and integrated over. Then you can integrate by parts to get the sign back.

Comment: In other words $\langle \phi | l_x^\dagger |\psi \rangle = (l_x |\phi \rangle )^\dagger | \psi \rangle =  \langle l_x \phi | \psi \rangle$, so you can think of $\tfrac{d}{dx}^\dagger$ as a derivative operator that acts on everything to its left. To make it useful again, you will integrate by parts, and this cancels out the minus sign on the $i$.

Comment: Anyway I think your logic is OK. Just make sure you stay inside an integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to answer the following question as a warm-up. What can you say about the expectation value of the $1D$ momentum operator $p = -i \hbar \tfrac{d}{dx}$ of a real wavefunction? Note that the expectation value itself should be real, because momentum is a real quantity (and the operator is hermitian).

Comment: I'm trying not to give away the answer. You know the representation of $l_x = y pz - z py$, so you can see what happens. Do you know of any simple representations of any of the angular momentum operators?

Also, I would be interested if anyone can hint towards a representation independent solution.

Comment: Ok I think I've got it my answers above thx :)